# Powerpoint - find a specified word in a text box within a group and add a comment

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am looking to search for a specified word or phrase in a presentation and then add a comment to all slides where it appears.  I have the below code which works well, however I want to be be able to search for text boxes that are in groups (the below code only searches in text boxes)

Any suggestions would be really appreciated.

```
Sub FindWordAndAddComment()
    Dim sld As Slide
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim txtRng As TextRange, rngFound As TextRange
    Dim i As Long, n As Long
    Dim TargetList

'enter or word phrase here
    TargetList = Array("this is a test")

    For Each sld In Application.ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each shp In sld.Shapes
            If shp.HasTextFrame Then
                Set txtRng = shp.TextFrame.TextRange

                For i = 0 To UBound(TargetList)
                    Set rngFound = txtRng.Find(TargetList(i))

                    Do While Not rngFound Is Nothing
                        n = rngFound.Start + 1
                                           
                        With sld.Comments.Add(12, 12, "found", "me", "'this is a test' has been found")
                        
                            
                            
                            Set rngFound = txtRng.Find(TargetList(i), n)
                        
                        End With
                    
               
                    
                    Loop
                Next
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumes that all groups have the default "Group" name:

```
Dim sld As Slide
Dim shp As Shape
Dim txtRng As TextRange, rngFound As TextRange
Dim i As Long, n As Long
Dim TargetList(2) As String

Sub FindWordAndAddComment()
'enter or word phrase here
    TargetList(0) = "This is a test"
    TargetList(1) = "This is a text"
    TargetList(2) = "Here we go"
    For Each sld In Application.ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each shp In sld.Shapes
            If InStr(shp.Name, "Group") <> 0 Then
                For X = 1 To shp.GroupItems.Count
                    If shp.GroupItems(X).HasTextFrame Then
                        Set txtRng = shp.GroupItems(X).TextFrame.TextRange
                        FindTextAddComment
                    End If
                Next X
            Else
                If shp.HasTextFrame Then
                    Set txtRng = shp.TextFrame.TextRange
                    FindTextAddComment
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub

Sub FindTextAddComment()
    For i = 0 To UBound(TargetList)
        Set rngFound = txtRng.Find(TargetList(i))
        Do While Not rngFound Is Nothing
            n = rngFound.Start + 1
            With sld.Comments.Add(12, 12, "found", "me", "'this is a test' has been found")
                Set rngFound = txtRng.Find(TargetList(i), n)
            End With
        Loop
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Exactly what was needed.  Also works much faster than my original code.  Many thanks

Comment: If you find the code useful, please give my answer an upvote. Thanks!